# Order by FIELD not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql query:

```
select *
from qbs_question_options
where qbs_opt_id in (28445, 28446, 28447, 28449, 28448, 28444)
ORDER BY FIELD(qbs_qst_id, 28445, 28446, 28447, 28449, 28448, 28444)
```

I didn't get the result as of the order mentioned above in `ORDER BY FIELD`. The above query reults in `ASC` order. How do get these?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me. How did you test it? I mean in some program like sql manager? Maybe it's doing additional sorting.

Comment: Can you post some sample data so that we are able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Is it on purpose that you limit on `qbs_opt_id`, but order on `qbs_qst_id` using the same values?

Comment: @dragoste via phpMyadmin